# Any suggestion to redirect an URL with colon to another URL

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, url, redirect

I'm working on a project and need to redirect old URLs to new ones.

But old URLs something like

```
/test/#mytest:parta
/test/#mytest:partb
/test/#mytest:partc
/test/#yourtest:partx
/test/#yourtest:partz
```

Since those URLs including # and : it's not easy to forward from the server side and also tried to perform that action with a plugin on WordPress also not possible.

Any suggestions about this? Thank you

Comment: "it's not easy to forward from the server side” - by that you mean not possible since that is never sent to the server. The short answer is that you need to do it all client-side somehow, which means JS